# fourier transform for non-stationary signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing, fourier

I have read that for non-stationary signal we break the signal into smaller segments by applying a window function . My question is how this can help to make the signal has a fixed features or to became stationary signal even it's not?

Comment: I know what a stationary process is, but I've never heard of a stationary signal...

Comment: @VladimirCravero A stationary signal is one whose frequency does not changes over time.

Comment: That's quite a new definition for me. Have you got some reference for me? I think you are mixing things up either with *periodic* vs *non periodic* signals or with the *power spectral density* of a process, that is the F-transform of its autocorrelation iff the process is stationary, but I may be wrong of course :)

Comment: maybe a stationary signal is a signal which FFT does not change "too much" over time?

Comment: @VladimirCravero from wiki answers http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_non-stationary_signal , is says that a nonstationary signal is one whose frequency changes over time.So the sationary signal is the  signal is one whose frequency does not changes over time ! :)

Comment: I've seen that link, I don't agree much with the definition. It seems to me that "stationary" and "periodic" means the same thing in this context, and this does not seem very good to me. If that's what you mean maybe your question is equivalent to "how do you F-transform non periodic signals". I really don't get why you need the window function. If you can provide an example that'd be great: take a non-stationary signal and then break it.

Comment: actually im asking on EEG signal in specific , but i make it general to all nonstationary signal .  _I really don't get why you need the window function_ and that's my question !

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I really don't understand your question then. State your problem, i.e. what you have and what you want to obtain, helping would be so much easier then.

Comment: @VladimirCravero you right to doubt the use of terminology.  A process is stationary if it's mean and higher moments are independent of t. The PDF of a stationary process is independent of time shift in the strict reading of the meaning. This means that it must be on for all time.  That linked article from wiki answer is misleading.

Comment: @placeholder thanks. I know what (weak|wide-sense|cyclo|ergodic) stationarity is for a process, but the extension to a causal signal was not clear to me. And that's because there's no extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discrete Fourier transform works on the assumption that your signal is *periodic*.

So, say we start with this arbitrary time-domain signal:

[image]

If it's periodic, we should be able to repeat it:

[image]

Well I guess that works, but we've introduced a discontinuity. This is like adding a square wave to your signal: you are going to see a new frequency component emerge equal to the DFT period, plus all of its odd harmonics.

In other words, the DFT sees any discontinuities even if they are at the ends of the signal. In fact, since the signal is periodic, it doesn't matter if we rotate all the inputs. If we do that with our original, we end up with:

[image]

This is exactly the same input as the first, as far as the DFT is concerned.

A window function works by tapering the ends to some similar value (usually 0) gradually, thereby making them equal. But it does so gradually, so that a minimum of extra frequency components are introduced. If we apply a window function to our original signal, you get something like this:

[image]

Which when duplicated, gives you:

[image]

or rotated:

[image]

No discontinuities! Now our non-periodic signal looks like a periodic signal, and we made it so while introducing a minimum of frequency-domain distortion. Of course, [different window functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#A_list_of_window_functions) define "minimum distortion" in different ways, according to what you are trying to accomplish with the transform.

Comment: But do you really call non periodic signals also "stationary" signals?

Comment: @VladimirCravero I think what the OP had in mind was [stationary process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process), which is certainly related but not the same. The approach, so far as I can infer, is to take a non-stationary process and slice it into short time segments, such that each segment is approximately stationary, then analyze that segment. That's rather orthogonal to the periodic requirement of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Well thanks, that's what I thought. A "stationary signal" is a misuse of words.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Maybe so, but I understood the question to be "why do we need a window function?", and as it turns out, the reason has nothing to do with stationary anything, though there seems to be some assumption by the OP to the contrary.

Comment: You've got a point. Maybe OP cofusion is just confusing me. I find your answer more than adequate for this question though.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is a little unclear on what you want to do with the signal but going by the Fourier and Signal Processing tags on the post I guess you want to process your non-stationary signal in some way like an FFT or something.

The FFT considers the signal to be periodic in the window in which it is applied. So if you apply 2048 samples to the FFT it's assumed that the next 2048 are exactly the same, as are the 2048 preceeding values etc..

The purpose of the window is to reduce the weighting of the signal at the ends of the window so that the assumed periodicity in the window size has a reduced affect on the FFT. In reality there is an effect; causing side lobes on the signal of interest. Different window types produce different magnitudes of side lobes (e.g. Hamming, Blackman etc..).

Specifically in your case of a non-stationary signal the window would serve to "narrow down" the signal to a small segment that could be considered to be stationary for the purposes of the FFT.

The windows themselves have an FFT spectum that cause the lobes and leakage. See how a rectangular window (same as no window) has significant leakage and lobes:
[image]

These are reduced significantly in a simple triangular window:
[image]

This is significant for you because it "separates" your time variant signal periods from one another, allowing processing such as an FFT or Auto-correlation function.